# Showing if $f^{-1}(D_1)$ $\subseteq$ $f^{-1}(D_2)$ then $D_1 \subseteq D_2$ on certain conditions

Tags: functions

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a surjection and let $D_1$,$D_2$$\subseteq$B. Show if $f^{-1}(D_1)$ $\subseteq$ $f^{-1}(D_2)$ then $D_1 \subseteq D_2$

The second part of this question is. 
Construct an example that shows the above is not true if $f$ is not a surjection.

I can draw a set in my head but I can't seem to interpret the proof in words...

Also, does  $f^{-1}(D_1)$ $\subseteq$ $f^{-1}(D_2)$ imply $f:A \rightarrow D_1$ ,$f:A\rightarrow D_2$ is bijective?

Comment: It certainly not implies bijectivity because injectivity is far from obvious.

Comment: Pick $D_1 \subseteq f(A)$ and $D_2 \subseteq B \setminus f(A)$.  If $f$ is not surjective, $B\setminus f(A) \neq \emptyset$ and we can pick a non-empty $D_2$.  What can you say about $D_1$, $D_2$, and their pre-images?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in D_1$, since $f$ is a surjection, $\exists y \in A, f(y)=x.$

$y \in f^{-1}(D_1)$.

Since $f^{-1}(D_1) \subseteq f^{-1}(D_2)$, $y \in f^{-1}(D_2)$

Hence $x=f(y) \in D_2$.

Hence $D_1 \subseteq D_2$.

To construct the example to show the result may not hold if we do not have surjection.

Let $f: (-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=x^2$.

Let $D_1=[0,2]$, $D_2=[0,1]$.  Can you verify that $f^{-1}(D_1) \subseteq f^{-1}(D_2)$ but $D_1 \not \subseteq D_2$ ?

To answer your last question, let $D_1=D_2=[0,1)$. Can you verify whether $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow D_1$ where $f(x)=x^2$ is a bijection?